# Remote Connection of Rpi3 using VNC/RDP

Tags: vnc, rdp

I have inserted flashed SD with raspbian - installed tightvncserver  and was able to connect using Remmina(VNC & RDP) via IP address. But now when I try to connect using VNC, I get

> Unable to connect to VNC server

and RDP gives

> Unable to establish a connection to RDP server

Tried with other application **Remote Desktop Viewer** and it gives

> Connection to host was closed

I had executed some commands (**sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**) in Rpi3. Now I have no access to Rpi3 to check wheather VNC is disabled. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why are you using Debian? Raspbian has RealVNC included. What have you done on the Pi?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake - I have installed Raspbian image. I tried with RealVNC and getting `Connection was refused by the computer`

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md if you have proplems you need to explain WHAT **YOU** did.